What does this "crossed wave" symbol mean?
What is this symbol?

I'm not a piano player, although I know a couple of accents (marcato, tenuto, staccato, staccatissimo), and this is not one of them.

Interestingly, the duplicate question asks about the same measures of the same piece!
